# Mouse cursor jumps to the start of a string in an text input field in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

When I click on a text field that has text in it, and set the focus to the end of a string (as most people would normally do) the focus of the cursor jumps to the start of the string.

This only happens in IE. The app is MVC 2 with jquery and javascript.

How would one go about debugging this behavior? I can not use firebug, as this is an IE only behavior. IE Developer tools "Script" tab reveals little to no info that helps me debug.

I've combed through our jquery, and nothing jumps out as the cause.

What steps would you take in debugging this issue. Could CSS cause this type of behavior?? I would not think so.

Possibly, it could be the LABEL/INPUT element layout... that could be a factor for sure.

Here is the form HTML. The javascript is very limited and would not cause this issue, so for the sake of breivity I will only show this form snippet:

```
<div>
                        <span class="field">
                            <div><label for="Input_Sku" style="width: 130px;">SKU:</label><span class="field"><input id="Input_Sku" name="Input.Sku" type="text" value="" /><span></span></span><p class="message"></p></div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="field">
                            <div><label for="Input_ProductName" style="width: 130px;">Product Name:</label><span class="field"><input id="Input_ProductName" name="Input.ProductName" type="text" value="professional" /><span></span></span><p class="message"></p></div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

EDIT:

Here is the Javascript code, which is fairly limited:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  

         $('#reset').bind('click', function() {$('form').clearForm();});
        $(".tbl").tablesorter({ debug: false }); 
        $(".boxname").bind('click', function () {
            $('.tog').toggle();$('.a').toggle();$('.b').toggle();
        });
        $.fn.clearForm = function() {location.reload();};
</script>
```

And the script references:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

One possible solution which I should have done first was run the page through JS Lint and then remove script references one at a time to see if the behavior goes away - but I am going for the "constructively lazy" approach here.

EDIT #2

I tried the solution from [this post][1], using this code block:

```
    var el = $("#Input_Sku");
        el[0].onfocus = el[0].onblur = null;
        $(el).on("focus blur", function(e) {
            this.value = $.trim(this.value);    
            if ((e.type === "focus") && this.createTextRange) {
                var r = this.createTextRange();
                r.moveStart("character", this.value.length);
                r.select();
            }
        });
```

But it only works half way. It will position the cursor to the end of the string on INITIAL FOCUS, but after that, any sort of click or cursor movement in any text field in the page causes the cursor to jump back to the front! Frustrating.

I need to start eliminating scripts that could cause this I guess; it will be a huge pain, but this bug has become a show stopper - so I am getting desperate.

Comment: I don't think the problem is present in the HTML code... Can you give us the JS code ? I don't think CSS is related to this behavior. BTW, about Firebug, have a look to Firebug Lite, you might like it :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've added the javascript code. PS I'm checking out firebug lite right now!! thanks :)

Comment: The `on` method was added in the version 1.7, and you're using the 1.4.2 http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not able to upgrade our jquery code base, so I will have to find another solution. Is there a 1.4.2 equivalent?

Comment: I've updated to 1.7.1 and this hack will fix it on initail focus, but the cursor still jumps, on input click for example. SO this will not work... any other suggestions. I'm stuck.

Comment: I've solved this problem, and the culprit was a "display: inline-block;" tag on a text input field. I have no idea why, but IE9 does not like that attribute, and either block or inline doesn't product the same effect. Bizarre...