# Mark.js contenteditable - run Mark on input

Tags: javascript, mark.js

I'm am making a "word-checker" with a `contenteditable` div while using mark.js to highlingt certain words/word groups.

The problem I am having is that I can't find a way to "run" Mark.js as the words are being typed (copy/pasted) in.

I have tried to achieve this by adding an event listener to the textarea, but that throws an error: *mark is not defined.* `textarea.addEventListener("input", mark);` and by changing mark to instance `textarea.addEventListener("input", instance);` which gives me an error: *TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.*. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upb8y5kn/4/).

I have also looked at various examples found on SO and on google, but I just can't seem to find what I'm looking for. The closest thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680080/how-to-highlight-different-search-results-with-mark-js), but I still couldn't get it to [work](https://jsfiddle.net/ew4x27ku/).

Any help would be much appreciated. If I can provide any additional information, please let me know.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var instance = new Mark("div.textarea");

var red   = ["red", "blood"];
var brown = ["brown", "pudding"];
var green = ["green", "grass"];

instance.mark(red, {
   seperateWordSearch: false,
   className: "red",
   "accuracy": {
      "value": "exactly",
      "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
   }
});


instance.mark(brown, {
   seperateWordSearch: false,
   className: "brown",
   "accuracy": {
      "value": "exactly",
      "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
   }
});

instance.mark(green, {
   seperateWordSearch: false,
   className: "green",
   "accuracy": {
      "value": "exactly",
      "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
   }
});

textarea.addEventListener("input", mark);
```

```css
.red {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}

.green{
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.brown{
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<h2>Text checker</h2>
<div class="textarea" id="textarea" contenteditable="true">
   I hate blood pudding and so do you.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the `instance.mark(...)` calls to a separate function (e.g. `markWords`).
You can then call that function when the input text changes:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var instance = new Mark("div.textarea");

var red   = ["red", "blood"];
var brown = ["brown", "pudding"];
var green = ["green", "grass"];

//create a function which will highlight all specified words
var markWords = function() {
  instance.mark(red, {
     seperateWordSearch: false,
     className: "red",
     "accuracy": {
        "value": "exactly",
        "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
     }
  });


  instance.mark(brown, {
     seperateWordSearch: false,
     className: "brown",
     "accuracy": {
        "value": "exactly",
        "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
     }
  });

  instance.mark(green, {
     seperateWordSearch: false,
     className: "green",
     "accuracy": {
        "value": "exactly",
        "limiters": [",", ".", "!", "?"]
     }
  });
}

//call the markWords function to do the initial highlighting
markWords();

//setup listener to call function markWords
textarea.addEventListener("input", markWords);
```

Comment: Thank you. tt works. There is one issue though. Once I type in *green*, it throws the cursor/type-indicator to the beginning of the word. Any idea why and how to fix that?

Comment: It looks like a bug in mark.js, try opening an issue: https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues/new

Comment: Thank you. I found a similar issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405450/mouse-cursor-jumps-to-the-start-of-a-string-in-an-text-input-field-in-ie . Any idea how I could work around this?

Comment: I've had a look at these issues https://github.com/julmot/mark.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+caret+is%3Aclosed , but I didn't find a workaround. I also tried calling the subsequent invocations of `instance.mark` from the `done` callback function mentioned in the documentation (https://markjs.io/), but that was also of no help.

Comment: Posted an issue on github. Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated. Will open a new question on SO, hopefully someone knows a workaround.