# Move cursor at end of Input jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery code which does some thing on focus. But on focus mouse cursor moves to start position in IE

```
var sea = $("#ct");
        sea.focus(function (e) {
         var season = sea.val();
         if (season == "") {
           sea.val($('#<%=lbl.ClientID%>').text());
         }
   });
```

Comment: maybe u can put your code on JSfiddle or try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4255855/4173608

Comment: I need to do few thing on focus.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code.

```
var SearchInput = $('#ct');
SearchInput.val(SearchInput.val() + ' World!');
var strLength= SearchInput.val().length;
SearchInput.focus();
SearchInput[0].setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);
```

JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ayrd/

thanks

Comment: As tyou can see in my code i need to do few things on focsus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things ON Focus you can try this:

```
 var sea = $("#ct");
 sea.on('focus', function () {
     var season = sea.val();
     if (season == "") {
       sea.val($('#<%=lbl.ClientID%>').text());
     }
 });
```

Haven't tested it yet...